# HTML to PDF using Javascript with scrollable tables and graphs (Vertically and Horizontally)

Tags: javascript, html, html-to-pdf

I am trying to create an HTML to PDF function on my website using javascript. I am currently using html2pdf.js. However, I have some tables and graphs which are scrollable (Horizontally and vertically), so the HTML to pdf function only prints out the beginning parts of the tables and graphs instead of the full image.

Can anyone give some suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a workaround can be removing/modifying the height and width limits in the styles of HTML file just before calling the PDF creation function and restore it back after the PDF creation.

You can use DOM manipulation function such as `getElementById` to do this easily.